# vuetify tabs slow for map rendering

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I am using a vuetify tabs.

```
<VTabs
          row
          justify-end
          show-arrows
          slider-color="accent"
          @change="changedTab"
        >
          <VTab key="btn1">Tab 1</VTab>
          <VTab key="btn2">Tab 2</VTab>
          <VTab key="btn3">Tab 3</VTab>
          <VTab key="btn4">Tab 4</VTab>
          <VTabItem key="panel1">
            <SessionMapInformation
              :data="data0"
            ></SessionMapInformation>
          </VTabItem>

          <VTabItem key="panel2">
            <SessionMapInformation
              :data="data1"
            ></SessionMapInformation>
          </VTabItem>

          <VTabItem key="panel3">
            <SessionMapInformation
              :data="data2"
            ></SessionMapInformation>
          </VTabItem>

          <VTabItem key="panel4">
            <SessionMapInformation
              :data="data3"
            ></SessionMapInformation>
          </VTabItem>
        </VTabs>
```

SessionMapInformation shows map and markers depending on **:data** props.

The thing is, it's so slow between changing tabs that sometimes if :data is a little bit of huge, the screen freezes. What workaround would you advice ?

Comment: did you try [keep-alive](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#keep-alive-with-Dynamic-Components)

Comment: that's for something else. still slow.

Comment: any chance you can get a running codesanbox/jsfiddle to show?

Comment: It slows down if you have huge array filter operation and used data in computed, and then data is used in map. Instead you can pause by showing loading icon , once the data manipulation is done, you can show the map

Comment: It also depends what you are rendering inside your SessionMap component. If you are rendering 1000s of dom elements, that will definitely slow things down